# Most Efficient Way To Consolidate Multiple Byte Arrays Received Over Async Network?

Tags: c#, sockets

Basically, what I'm looking to do is find an effective means of consolidating large amounts of data that would be too large for a suitable buffer size.

For something like an instant messenger setting a fixed buffer size is a fine solution as most people accept that instant messages tend to have a limit.

However if I were to want to send a whole text document multiple pages long, you would not want to have to send it 2048 characters at a time. Or whatever you define as the limit.

I've represented my current solution in some pseudo code:

```
public class Pseudo
{
    public const int m_BufferSize = 255;

    public void SendAllData(Socket socket, byte[] data)
    {
        int byteCount = data.Length;

        if (byteCount <= m_BufferSize)
        {
            Socket.Send(data);
        }

        else if (byteCount > m_BufferSize)
        {
            int wholeSegments = Math.Floor(byteCount / m_BufferSize);
            int remainingBytes = byteCount % m_BufferSize;
            int bytesSent = 0;
            int currentSegment = 1;

            string id = Guid.NewGuid();

            byte[] tempData = data;

            //Send initial packet creating the data handler object.
            Socket.SendInitial(id);

            while (bytesSent < byteCount)
            {
                if (currentSegment <= wholeSegments)
                {
                    Socket.Send(tempData[m_BufferSize]);
                    tempData.CopyTo(tempData, m_BufferSize);
                    bytesSent += m_BufferSize;
                }

                else
                {
                    Socket.Send(tempData[remainingBytes]);
                    bytesSent += remainingBytes;
                }

                currentSegment++;
            }

            //Let The Server Know Send Is Over And To Consolidate;
            Socket.SendClose(id);

        }
    }

    internal class DataHandler
    {
        string m_Identity;
        List<byte[]> m_DataSegments = new List<byte[]>();

        static Dictionary<string, DataHandler> 
            m_HandlerPool = new Dictionary<string, DataHandler>();

        public DataHandler(string id)
        {
            m_Identity = id;

            if (!m_HandlerPool.ContainsKey(id))
            {
                m_HandlerPool.Add(this);
            }
        }

        public void AddDataSegment(byte[] segment)
        {
            m_DataSegments.Add(segment);
        }

        public byte[] Consolidate(string id)
        {
            var handler = m_HandlerPool(id);
            List<byte> temp = new List<byte[]>();

            for (int i = handler.m_DataSegments.Length; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                temp.Add(handler.m_DataSegments[i]);
            }

            Dispose();
            return temp;
        }

        void Dispose()
        {
            m_DataSegments = null;
            m_HandlerPool.Remove(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically what this is doing is assigning an identifier to individual packets so that they can be using AsyncEventArgs, as the may not necessarily all be received without being interrupted so I can't really rely on index.

These are then stored in the object 'DataHandler' and consolidated into a single byte array.

The problem is, as you can tell, it's going to add a lot of overhead in what I had hoped to be a high-performance socket server. Even if I were to pool the handler objects, the whole thing feels crufty.

Edit: It's also going to require a delimiter which I really don't want to use.

So, what would be the most efficient way of accomplishing this?

Edit: Example code for the method of processing data, this came from one of the async code projects.

```
    internal void ProcessData(SocketAsyncEventArgs args)
    {
        // Get the message received from the client.
        String received = this.sb.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine("Received: \"{0}\". The server has read {1} bytes.", received, received.Length);

        Byte[] sendBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(received);
        args.SetBuffer(sendBuffer, 0, sendBuffer.Length);

        // Clear StringBuffer, so it can receive more data from a keep-alive connection client.
        sb.Length = 0;
        this.currentIndex = 0;
    }
```

This is populating the user token data which is what is referenced by *this.*

```
                    // Set return buffer.
                    token.ProcessData(e);
```

Comment: This `List<byte> temp = new List<byte[]>();` won't compile.

Comment: Why you need to store all buffers in memory? you can consolidate it without having in memory.

Comment: @easuter1 Yeah, it's just a typo. None of that code is meant to compile.

Comment: Best way is to put a byte count at beginning of each array.  The receiver will read count and then read number of bytes, then look for new byte count.

Comment: @gabba The reason it's in memory is because consolidating them without doing so would make you rely on consolidating what you got based on the order in which you got it.

Comment: @En'gai, In that case you can store just unordered part of data and when you get some ordered pieces, you can write it to some storage. Better if you write it also async

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using TCP/IP - and if so, I don't understand the problem you're trying to fix. You can keep sending data as long as the connection is stable. Under the hood, TCP/IP will automatically create numbered packets for you, and ensure they arrive in the same order they were sent.

On the receiving end, you will have to read to a buffer of a certain size, but you can immediately write the received data to a `MemoryStream` (or `FileStream` if you intend to store the data on disk).

Comment: Sorry if my explanation is lacking.. basically I want to be able to send file larger than the buffer size using an async network and because this would take multiple sends and it is asynchronous there's a chance that , I believe, if I am just writing all incoming data to a stream in the order in which it's received that I might get a scrambled message if one decides to block for a minute and another one gets through.

Comment: Are you using TCP/IP? If so, and you've seen scrambled data, you have to make sure you write the received data to the stream _before_ initiating another `Receive` operation - otherwise the buffer can be overwritten while you're processing it.

Comment: I added a block of code at the bottom. Are you saying that I can write the received data to a stream and they won't scramble up? How would I know at what point to process the stream? Just an end message?

Comment: An end message is hard to implement, because who knows the data might contain that exact sequence, and you'd have to escape it. An easier approach is send the size of the data up front, as a fixed size block of data. And yes, TCP/IP is a "streaming" protocol, where the order of bytes is maintained. Just don't tell the socket to continue receiving on a buffer before you have processed that buffer.

Comment: @En'gai, If you want to reorder packets you can use stream only after reordering somewhere

Comment: @gabba TCP/IP guarantees the order of packets, there is no need for reordering.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis, that's true. I just saying IF some reordering is needed.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis - So, I get that tcp is going to send each byte array in order, but is it not going to send each message out of order? Or rather, have a possibility to? It's not the 255 bytes I'm worried about being out of order. Sorry for so many questions, just trying to understand. Or are you saying have one stream per token object that SAEA uses?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't respond earlier - as long as your socket remains connected, all data sent is received in exactly that order, regardless of whether you send it 1 byte at a time or in large chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually high performance server:

- use async send/receive methods
- don't store all received data in memory (if you want to store many data use some blob storage services)
- if you need, you can store some unordered pieces in some reusable context, and resend it to storage as soon as posible
- reuse buffers, don't allocate new buffer on each receive/send action
- etc...